# Raspberry Pi Bullseye Splash Video

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, vlc

I'm trying to setup a custom video splash screen before an app loads up.
It used to be really easy using omxplayer but it's now depreciated and I can't get it to install. All the posts I've found have just said use VLC with no explanation on how to do so.

I've tried making a systemd service with the following and a few variations but none are working

```
[Unit]
Description=Splash screen
DefaultDependencies=no
After=local-fs.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/cvlc --play-and-exit /path/to/video/video.mp4
StandardInput=tty
StandardOutput=tty

[Install]
WantedBy=sysinit.target
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer

```
[Unit]
Description=Splash screen
Before=systemd-user-sessions.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/cvlc --play-then-stop /path/to/video.mp4
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sh /home/obd/boot.sh
Type=simple
User=pi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```